# Auto tagging in google adwords

Tags: google-analytics, salesforce, google-ads-api

We are trying to setup AdWords Conversion Import for Salesforce and I am following this support document from google https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6299296?hl=en

The other part of this integration was to add auto tagging which will add the GCLID to our url parameters. But if we do auto tagging it will remove any other parameters that we use to track the campaign and stuff(for other third party analytics we use) including the UTM parameters. While I was researching I came up this article https://effinamazing.com/blog/manual-utm-tagging-vs-adwords-autotagging/ which says that we can have both gclid and other url parameters by using a hybrid method (**enabling auto tagging at adwords and Allow manual tagging (UTM values) to override auto-tagging (GCLID values**)) at Google Analytics.

My only concern is if we were do go this route and use this hybrid method, will I lose our exisiting URL parameters. Do we have to rebuild these URL Parameter again?

We have something like this right now:

> https://www.example.com/testurl/?Agency=Security&keyword={keyword}&network={network}&device={device}&mkwid={ifsearch:s}{ifcontent:c}6GxL6Evy_d{device}&pcrid={creative}&pkw={keyword}&pmt={matchtype}&utm_medium=Paid-Search&utm_source=Google&utm_campaign={campaignid}&utm_content={adgroupid}&utm_term={ifsearch:{keyword}|{matchtype}|{network}|{device}|{adposition}|{creative}}{ifcontent:{placement}||{network}}&sf_src_cmpid=q&region=NA

and after enabling these settings in GA and Adwords i am expecting to see something like this

> https://www.example.com/testurl/?Agency=Security&keyword={keyword}&network={network}&device={device}&mkwid={ifsearch:s}{ifcontent:c}6GxL6Evy_d{device}&pcrid={creative}&pkw={keyword}&pmt={matchtype}&utm_medium=Paid-Search&utm_source=Google&utm_campaign={campaignid}&utm_content={adgroupid}&utm_term={ifsearch:{keyword}|{matchtype}|{network}|{device}|{adposition}|{creative}}{ifcontent:{placement}||{network}}&sf_src_cmpid=q&region=NA&**gclid=google_gclid_here**

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: "See" them where?  Auto-tagging does not remove parameters.  It only appends the GCLID param.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-tagging appends the GCLID to your URLs.  It doesn't remove parameters, as that would break the very things you are mentioning.